# How to translate the parts of Chinese university

Tags: vocabulary

How to distinguish "大学", "学院", "系". "专业"?

As myself, I'm in "中国海洋大学数学科学学院数学系信息与计算科学专业". How to translate it properly?

And another question: What is "国家保密学院"? Is "国家" describing "保密: or "学院"? I don't know it even as a native Mandarin speaker.

Comment: I think 国家 modifies 保密... 国家保密学院 could be college of national secrecy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/difference-between-%E9%83%A8%E9%97%A8-and-%E7%B3%BB), the university system in China is organized somewhat differently than the United States:

#### Chinese Universities *(please offer corrections)*

- At the top level, there is a `大学`, which is usually translated as `University`.
- There are groupings of related departments called `学院`. Because this is not always similar to US universities, the translations vary. In order to translate `X学院` [I've seen](http://www.nankai.edu.cn/english/schools.htm):

  - `institute of X`
  - `X school` (especially "Business School" and "Law School")
  - `college of X`
- Individual `departments` (which may have one or more related majors) are `系`.
- Courses of study towards a degree are called `专业`, translated as `major`.

#### US Universities and Colleges

- At the top level you have either `University` or `College` (both show up as `大学`). Universities are bigger than Colleges and have more administrative subdivisions..
- Universities (but *not* colleges) may be subdivided into various `schools` or `colleges`.

  - Professional schools (business, law, medicine) are basically always a separate "school" from undergraduate programs. For instance, Harvard University includes the [Harvard Business School](http://www.hbs.edu/Pages/default.aspx) and the [Harvard Law School](http://www.law.harvard.edu/index.html). Admissions for professional schools are always separate from admissions for undergraduate programs.
  - Undergraduate programs in a university might all be lumped into a single "college" (e.g., [UT-Austin College of Undergraduate Studies](http://www.utexas.edu/ugs/)), or there may be several "colleges" for related degrees. Generally, admission as an undergraduate into a University entitles you to take courses in *any* department or "school" that teaches undergraduates. For instance, you could start studying art and decide to study chemistry instead. If a student's major is part of some "college" or "school" within the university, they might not even know which one it is.
  - Sometimes graduate (Masters, PhD) programs are in their own "schools", and other times their part of the same "school" as related majors at the undergraduate level. For instance, UW-Madison has the [College of Letters & Sciences](http://www.ls.wisc.edu/about-departments.html) which includes many undergraduate majors and graduate programs in humanitites, social sciences, and sciences. Admissions for graduate programs are separate from undergraduate programs.
  - Music programs are sometimes in a separate "school" within the university called a "conservatory". Admissions might be separate from general undergraduate studies or require auditions.
- With a college or school, there are `departments`, which may offer one or more courses of study, generally called `majors`.

#### Second Question

国家保密学院 is a "School for the protection of state secrets". The Chinese government has [a bureau dedicated to this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Administration_for_the_Protection_of_State_Secrets).

Answer (score 1):

大学 is university.

学院, if a school on its own, is called college. As to a big 大学学院, it is usually called a Faculty (Commonwealth) or College (US usage) or School, up to the university's own choice.
For instance, 工学院 could be Faculty of Engineering or College of Engineering; U Waterloo has a Faculty of Mathematics (数学学院). 法学院, 商学院, 医学院 are usually schools (school of law / school of business / school of medicine) in US universities but Imperial College London has Faculty of Medicine.

系 is department, 专业 is major.

There are names invented by each university, I think one'd better translate them into something that is commonly seen, even if it deviates a little bit from the literal word-for-word translation. 中国海洋大学数学科学学院数学系信息与计算科学专业 seems 
`Major in Information and Computer Science, School of Mathematics at the Ocean University of China`.